# Django и защита ключей

Tags: python, django, шифрование, криптография, rsa

Пытаюсь понять как реализовано шифрование в Django и возник вопрос, на который не удалось пока найти ответа. 
Допустим я использую симметричные методы шифрования, скажем AES, как в таком случае защищается мой secret key? 
И аналогично для ассиметричного шифрования, RSA. Т.е. у меня минимум 2 ключа, но private key тоже нужно ведь как-то защитить. Будет ли это такой же метод как и в случае с secret key?

Comment: Как устроено шифрование чего? Паролей, куков(cookie), произвольных данных? В общем SECRET_KEY нужно хранить в секрете, чтобы его никто не узнал. Любые способы хранения на сервере небезопасны в случае угрозы (поэтому хранят просто в файле настроек) - безопасно было бы хранить на другом сервере и подтверждать запросы на получение ключа, но автоматизировать это не представляется возможным - если ваш сервер скомпрометирован, то все пропало.

Answer (score 0):

я такие вещи храню в environment

```
import os
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET']
```